# Creating an arbitrary state of the quantum simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics

Suppose $\mathcal{B}=\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle, ... \}$ is the energy eigen-basis of a quantum simple harmonic oscillator. I want to create the state
\begin{equation}
|\Psi\rangle = c_{0}|0\rangle + c_{1}|1\rangle + c_{2}|2\rangle + ...
\end{equation}
Besides the normalization condition
\begin{equation}
\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle = |c_{0}|^2+ |c_{1}|^2+ |c_{2}|^2+...=1,
\end{equation}
are there any other mathematical constrains on the complex amplitudes $c_0,c_1,c_2,...$?

Also, is there a protocol, perhaps from quantum optics, for creating an arbitrary $|\Psi\rangle$ as defined above?

*For example*, the complex amplitudes which define the state can be taken as
\begin{equation}
\{c_n\}=\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\zeta\left(3\right)}}\frac{1}{\left(1+n\right)^{3/2}} \},
\end{equation}
where $\zeta\left(3\right)\approx 1.202$ is given by the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). In this case, the normalization condition holds. Also, we get a nice finite value for the mean energy
\begin{equation}
\langle\Psi|\hat{n}|\Psi\rangle \approx0.019,
\end{equation}
where $\hat{n}=\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$ is the number operator (i.e. the Hermitian operator corresponding to the eigen-basis $\mathcal{B}$). **However**,the variance in the energy
\begin{equation}
\text{Var}[\hat{n}]=\langle\Psi|\hat{n}^2|\Psi\rangle-\langle\Psi|\hat{n}|\Psi\rangle^2 
\end{equation}
is infinite. Can such a state exist in nature?

Comment: There aren't any other constraints on the complex coefficients. Could you clarify what it is you're trying to do, or what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @KyleArean-Raines Thanks for the comment. To clarify: I have a set of complex amplitudes $\{c_0,c_1,c_2,...\}$ that satisfy the normalization condition. However, the resulting $|\Psi\rangle$ from such amplitudes is quite peculiar: It has a finite average energy, $\langle \Psi|\hat{n}|\Psi\rangle$, but the variance in the energy is infinite. Is this physically possible?

Here I have assumed that $a^{\dagger}a=\hat{n}$ is the number operators: i.e. $\hat{n}|n\rangle = n|n\rangle$ for all $n=0,1,2...$

Comment: "*This should not diverge.*" **Wrong.** Go back to basic probability; it very certainly *can* diverge, just as a Lorentzian has infinite variance, which manifests as the "kink" in its Fourier transform. We know from the Basel problem that $(6/\pi) [1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + \dots] = 1$ but obviously that has an infinite mean $(6/\pi) [1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ...]$; you can do the same with $1/n^3$ to get a finite mean but infinite variance.

Comment: Yes, I get $\langle \Psi | \hat{n} | \Psi \rangle$ to be finite and $\langle \Psi | \hat{n}^2 | \Psi \rangle$ diverges. For example, take $c_{n} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(1+n\right)^3}}$, where $\zeta(3)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). Then $\langle \Psi | \hat{n}^2 | \Psi \rangle$ will indeed diverge.

Comment: Ah yes, that was dumb. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: @Jas: I think you should add your example to your original question to be more clear. +1 for the nice example and question btw.

Comment: The notional state "can exist", in that there is little about it that is unacceptable. Its infinite linewidth suggests a vanishingly short-lived state. I'm not sure what applications you have in mind, but second time derivatives are bound to be dangerous. Perhaps your could use it as a limiting case for something.

Comment: @CosmasZachos It turns out that an infinite variance in energy (as defined above) means that the phase sensitivity (as quantified by the quantum fisher information) is arbitrarily large for this state. Thus it could have applications in quantum metrology.

Comment: My only advice is to compare it to the standard college physics paradigm for this sort of thing, as @CRDrost recommends: To wit, the sole bound state of the [δ-function potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential) has a kink at the origin, which amounts to the long tails of its Fourier transform the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), which is likewise momentless. So, the kink at the origin of time of your wave-function will be useful or not.   But QM is blasé and inured to this sort of thing....

Comment: In any case, [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apéry%27s_constant) is bread-and-butter in theoretical physics, and pops up all over the scene. But, as I indicated, it *behooves you* to compute the energy F.T. of this, so stick in the phase factors exp(-*i E(n) t*)s and  study the evident *Ψ(t)* s.